# How to specify column position when importing Gmail contents into a spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

When importing Gmail contents into a spreadsheet
If there is a specific item that is repeated
This is a Google app script where Lastrow is automatically added.

I want to specify the desired column position for each item.

Please help me.

```
function myFunction()
{
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:extra is:unread');
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('2021');

  for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++)
  {
    
    var plainBody = messages[i][0].getPlainBody();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    const regex=/ex0：(.*)\n(.*)ex1：(.*)\n(.*)ex2：(.*)\n/g;

    
    if(!plainBody.match(regex))
    {
      continue;
    }

    var data = plainBody.match(regex).map(x=>
    {
        var a0 = (/ex0：(.*)/).test(x)? RegExp.$1 : '0';
        var a1 = (/ex1：(.*)/).test(x)? RegExp.$1 : '0';
        var a2 = (/ex2：(.*)/).test(x)? RegExp.$1 : '0';

        return [a0, a1, a2];
    });

    
    sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
    
  }

  threads.forEach(function(thread) {
  thread.markRead();
  Utilities.sleep(100);
  });

}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. So, using the sample input and output values, can I ask you about the detail of `I want to specify the desired column position for each item.`?

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.
A separate function is assigned to certain blanks in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from `A separate function is assigned to certain blanks in the spreadsheet.`, I cannot still understand your question. I apologize for my poor English skill again. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: I just really appreciate your interest.

The column cells of the spreadsheet contain the spreadsheet-specific functions of the spreadsheet itself.

Thus, when Gmail contents are imported into a spreadsheet, the functions that existed in the cells of the spreadsheet forcibly disappear.

So, when importing Gmail data, it was necessary to specify the location of the column in Lastrow for each imported item.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand `So, when importing Gmail data, it was necessary to specify the location of the column in Lastrow for each imported item.`. For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Can you provide a sample spreadsheet to visually clarify what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

As a guess. Suppose your desired columns are: B, D, F. Then try to change this line

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

with this:

```
sheet.getRange('B' + lastRow).setValue(data[0]);
sheet.getRange('D' + lastRow).setValue(data[1]);
sheet.getRange('F' + lastRow).setValue(data[2]);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Thanks for thinking of a solution.

This solution could not be used because of the problem that LastRow's verdict was approaching 500000+.

But based on this solution, we are re-examining it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: { sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,4,data.length).setValue(data[0][2]); }  In this way, it is possible to specify a column, but If there are two or more duplicate items in the email content Only the first occurrence is recorded as a duplicate.  {sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);}  When using the first method, in the order from top to bottom Duplicates are added sequentially in descending order.

Comment: Well. Just to be sure -- so you solved your problem afte all? Does it need a help? I'm afraid I'm not exactly fluent in Google MailApp tricks, though.